# Update/get value from checkbox in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to get the bool value from a checkbox to my module in app.js to log bool value in console when changed.

I've looked at some examples, but I can only find answers for multiple checkboxes.

Inside my module (just an example):

```
        $scope.checkboxVal = function (bool) {
            console.log(bool);
        };
```

Checkbox:

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-change="checkboxVal(bool)" />
```

In the multiple checkbox guides I get that I can use a identifier for that rendered checkbox when ng-repeat is used, but how can I get it for only one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call checkboxVal, I think bool will be undefined, so you're not passing anything in. The right way to do this would be to bind the checkbox to a model value:

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-change="checkboxVal()" ng-model="bool" />
```

Then:

```
 $scope.checkboxVal = function () {
     console.log($scope.bool);
 };
```

Here's a video tutorial that has more detail on ng-change: https://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-using-the-ngchange-directive-in-angular

Comment: $scope.bool is also undefined even if I add a model.

Comment: You may need to provide more code. Off the top of my head: do you have your checkbox nested in ng-app and ng-controller directives and is your checkboxVal function inside your controller definition?

Comment: checkboxVal is inside my controller. I'm using routing with different forms (html-pages with different forms). It's inside one of these forms I'm trying to use this checkbox. Don't know if that helps but it's a lot of code to paste here.

Comment: Ah, sorry. I've solved it now. Missed a part in the code I was not aware of, and now your solution works. Thanks.